# Como se diz 'case' em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

Na programação usamos com frequência os nomes `camelCase`, `snake_case`, `PascalCase` para indicar o padrão de escrita das palavras.

Existe uma tradução dessa palavra 'case' em portugês?

Pensei em 'capitalização', mas no caso de snake_case não estamos mudando maiúsculas/minúsculas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na sua origem, este ***case*** corresponde ao português ***caixa***. Nomeadamente, a letra maiúscula também se chama [***caixa alta*** (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/caixa), ou ***upper case*** em inglês; e a minúscula, [***caixa baixa***](https://dicionario.priberam.org/caixa), ou ***lower case*** em inglês. Isto veio da prática nas tipografias de guardar os carateres móveis numa caixa com divisões, ficando as maiúsculas na parte superior, e as minúsculas na inferior. Ver [etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/case#etymonline_v_5433) e [Wikipédia](https://www.etymonline.com/word/case#etymonline_v_5433).

Encontrei na net alguns exemplos, poucos, de *caixa camelo* ou *caixa de camelo* com este sentido, mas o mais comum, como era de esperar, é usar-se o termo inglês mesmo em textos em português.

Comment: Se até os franceses [parecem usar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) o termo em inglês, devem ser pouquíssimos os que traduzem.

Comment: @stafusa, sim, os exemplos que eu encontrei foram muito poucos. E de uma leitura na diagonal, boa parte pareceram-se ser de pessoas a explicar o que é *camelCase*, não a usar o termo. Encontrei foi [*caja camello* na Wikipédia em espanhol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase